# Download all media files from webpage

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, wget

How to download all media files(pictures + Videos) from a webpage?!

Any app is acceptable but `wget` is preferable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is in [the man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man1/wget.1.html).

Anyway, `-p` is the switch you are looking for

```
wget -p www.example.com/index.html
```

However, I guess it will not be able to do some clever things (involving *javascript*). It depends on your page.

Answer (score 3):

`wget` has a mirror option (`-m`) that can go through a site and make a local copy. It's like the prerequisites (`-p`) option except that it'll follow every link on the domain and download all the pages on the site (that are linked in). If you only need files on one page, `-p` is enough.

If you're planning on mirroring the pages you can use the `-k` option to fix links. This is completely optional and isn't necessary if you're only after assets.

One problem I've had while doing this is some sites use a robots.txt file to stop Google (et al) copying or caching their assets. `wget` normally adheres to this too but we can turn it off. It's worth doing this as a matter of course.

Put it all together and you end up with something like this:

```
wget -mke robots=off http://website
```

Answer (score 2):

Video Download helper is your easiest option:

[image]

- [Video DownloadHelper :: Add-ons for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/?src=ss)

---

`wget` is a bit trickier. You can `wget` a page:

- `wget www.example.com/page.html`

then parse it:

- `cat page.html | grep ".png"`

  and then download those images via the link, the previous command displays:
- `wget www.example.com/images/image.png`

Answer (score 0):

#### This extension has been discontinued in the new Firefox Quantum.

---

Firefox - DownThemAll Addon will do the job just fine.

- Launch the addon from the menu 'tools'->'DownThemAll! Tools'->'DownThemAll'
- Select 'Pictures and Media' from the top tab/menu.
- Click Start.

See screenshot below:

[image]